# Redirect hard coded log file path to user directory

Tags: linux

I have a program that I can't modify that is hard coded to write to a log file located at `/tmp/myprogram.log`.

I need to be able to run multiple copies of this program on the same server as different users. Therefore I need the log files to be separated out.

I tried changing `/tmp/myprogram.log` to be a symlink pointing to `~/myprogram.log` thinking that this would mean that the program would write the log to the user directory of whatever user the program was running as, but unfortunately it's the shell that expands the `~` so that doesn't work.

Comment: Time for a chroot.

Comment: Or docker if you want to get fancy. Or syscall intercepts if you want to get hacky. Or find a better program.

Answer (score 1):

**I'd look into getting the source for your program and changing it.** 
I'd be a one liner. You could even post that one line here and we could help change it.

A chroot as suggested by others will work too though.

This talks about tricking your program to write to a different file... I couldn't get it to compile but the idea and discussion is there.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211394/redirect-a-file-descriptor-before-execution

Answer (score 0):

If you post the code which does the logging people could help here.

Because if it's use logger, you could have conf file or some app name via parameter specified, basicly some name which will do the different name for those multiple instances.

Next step will be tagging logger with this string and forward it to custom channel like 'local4'. For test you can log some msg by calling command `logger -p local4.info -t "YourTAG" "Log message"`

For finish set-up rsyslog to catch those tags in `/etc/rsyslog.d/your.conf`:
    
`:syslogtag,contains,"<YourTAG>"  -/path/to/name1.log
& stop
:syslogtag,contains,"<AnotherTAG>"  -/path/to/name2.log
& stop
.
local4.*  -/path/to/some.log # This will catch all tags which would't be mentioned before.
& stop`